# python error on adding meta-java in yocto

Tags: python, yocto

When I am compilingmeta-java on yocto 2.1 below error came.

Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:

```
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:install_relative_symlinks(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/kishore/balaji/project/chemito/toaster/poky/_toaster_clones/_git___git.yoctoproject.org_meta-java_krogoth/classes/relative_symlinks.bbclass', lineno: 4, function: install_relative_symlinks
     0001:do_install[postfuncs] += "install_relative_symlinks"
     0002:
     0003:python install_relative_symlinks () {
 *** 0004:    oe.path.replace_absolute_symlinks(d.getVar('D'), d)
     0005:}
Exception: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'replace_absolute_symlinks'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using yocto 2.1 (krogoth) then you need to use the krogoth branch of meta-java.  meta-java's master branch can and does use functions that are only in oe-core master (such as oe.path.replace_absolute_symlinks).

Comment: `ross@flashheart ~/Yocto/meta-java (master)
$ git checkout origin/krogoth
HEAD is now at 67e4869... libecj: fix build issues by adding missing dependencies`


`ross@flashheart ~/Yocto/meta-java ((67e4869...))
$ ls classes/
java.bbclass  java-library.bbclass  java-native.bbclass`


If you're getting the same error then you didn't change branches, as meta-java's krogoth branch doesn't have relative-symlinks.bbclass in.